# PHP set field-name with parameter

Tags: php, t-sql

in my php-script i am executing on a sql-server. Everything works fine, but: I dont only have variable values, but also variable field-names. Therefore I would like to pass the field-names as a parameter for security-reasons.

the sql would be

```
 $sql = "UPDATE  STA_Kunden
                SET     ? = ?
                WHERE   (KUN_KundeNo = ?)";

 $params = array($field, $value, $select);
```

But the field-name can not be a parameter. Therefore if someone would mess around with the field-name a sql-injection would be possible.
How can I set this secure?

Thanks
Max

Comment: Whitelisting is a sensible way to go. Or, maybe rethink your schema and/or your approach to building queries...usually having the field name completely dynamic isn't necessary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to whitelist the values of $field and concatenate it into the query:

```
if (in_array($field, array('allowed_field_1', 'allowed_field_2'))) {
  $sql = "UPDATE STA_Kunden SET " . $field . " = ? WHERE (KUN_KundeNo = ?)";
  $params = array($value, $select);
}
```

Comment: Accepted althoufh i might adopt this a little bit. Instead of accepting limited values (therefore need to list all field in a big database and need to change the code anytimw the database changes) i will not run further code if words like go, drop, insert, update,... (most commen sql-commands) with a space or newline before and behind are included. In thos case, looking for a field name, i could stop executing the code if any space is in the text submittet - even easier